# Type for extracting nested object keys

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have know type for some part of data and nested data structure which looks like:

```
interface Element {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface Elements {
    [name: string]: Partial<Element>;
}

interface Scopes {
    main: Elements;
    [other: string]: Elements;
}
```

Then I have a function which takes some object of `Scopes` type and also parameter which defined which scopes should I merge into output object (this will be flattened without scopes). The function might look like:

```
function merge<S extends Scopes>(obj: S, selectors?: { [K in keyof S]?: boolean }): UNKNOWNTYPE {
   // this will be some logic to extract and merge scopes
}
```

I have a problem with properly define output type for this function `UNKNOWNTYPE`. I want To dynamically flat and extract keys from input object so for folowing input data I will get this output:

```
const scopes: Scopes = {
  main : {
    a : {
       foo: "a"
    },
    b : {
       bar: "b"
    }
  },
  other : {
    b : {
       foo : "b"
    },
    c : {
       foo : "c"
    }
  }
}

const out = merge(scopes, { main : true, other : true });

/*
out is of this strcture

{
  a : {
    foo : "a"
  },
  b : {
    foo : "b"
    bar : "b"
  },
  c : {
    foo : "c"
  }
}
*/
```

I tried some approach and had tried such type but it does't resolve all merged scopes' keys:

```
interface UNKNOWNTYPE<Scopes, Scope extends keyof Scopes = keyof Scopes> {
    [K in keyof Scopes[Scope]: Element]
}
```

Is there any way to dynamically flatten and intersect 2nd level object from nested object?

Comment: Can you try and explain in simpler terms what you want to do? Is it just a matter of extracting 2nd level objects and combining them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I love this kind of thing.  First off: it's not really possible to do this in general; you'd need to be able to enumerate keys at the type level and TypeScript just isn't there (yet or maybe ever).  To the extent you can do it, you have to hold the type system's hand, since it is unlikely to be able to infer what you want it to do on its own.  That being said, here's a possible way forward:

Overload the function as many times as you expect the number of keys of `scopes` to be:

```
function merge<S extends Scopes, KA extends keyof S>(obj: S, selectors?: {[K in KA]?: boolean}): S[KA];
function merge<S extends Scopes, KA extends keyof S, KB extends keyof S>(obj: S, selectors?: {[K in KA | KB]?: boolean}): S[KA] & S[KB];
function merge<S extends Scopes, KA extends keyof S, KB extends keyof S, KC extends keyof S>(obj: S, selectors?: {[K in KA | KB | KC]?: boolean}): S[KA] & S[KB] & S[KC];
//... merge with 4, 5, 6, etc
function merge<S extends Scopes>(obj: S, selectors?: { [K in keyof S]?: boolean }): Elements {
   // this will be some logic to extract and merge scopes
  return null as any; // for now
}
```

Then, when you declare `scopes`, you probably shouldn't declare the type to be `Scopes`, or the type system will forget about the particular keys you set.  If you just let it infer a type, it will know all the keys and value types:

```
const scopes = {
  main : {
    a : {
       foo: "a"
    },
    b : {
       bar: "b"
    }
  },
  other : {
    b : {
       foo : "b"
    },
    c : {
       foo : "c"
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, you are ready to call `merge()`.  You have to explicitly specify the generic types.  The first one is the type of the `scopes` variable with all the keys and values you care about (which is just `typeof scopes` since we didn't set it to `Scopes`), and the next ones are the individual keys in `selectors`:

```
const out = merge<typeof scopes, 'main','other'>(scopes, { main: true, other: true });
out.a.foo; 
out.a.bar; // error as expected
out.b.foo;
out.b.bar;
out.c.foo;
out.c.bar; // error as expected
```

And you get an `out` of exactly the type you want. Is it worth all this hoop-jumping?  That's up to you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for explanation. I came with similar solution but it's not exactly that. The only thing I know is that `main` property will always be defined, and any other properties (and their names will be unknown) also the object can contain as many additional "scopes" as you want so writing many overloads seems to be an overkill. Seems like Typescript can;t handle this case dynamically as for now unfortunatelly.

Maybe I just tak scala-like approach then define 22 (arbitrary number for tuples) of overloads and return `Elements` otherwise. ;)